# Invalid input syntax for type bigint: in postgresql timescaledb

Tags: postgresql, csv, psql, bigint, timescaledb

I want to transfer data from a csv file named *TruckFleet_TruckCyclesQualityMatId.csv* to timescaledb.

The name of my db is ***cycles*** and the table's name is ***cycles_table***

The detailed view of my table is as follows:
[image: cycles_table]

when I try to insert data from the csv file to this table I am getting the

> ERROR: Invalid input syntax for type bigint: »HAUL_CYCLE_REC_IDENT«
> CONTEXT: COPY cycles_table, line 1, column HAUL_CYCLE_REC_IDENT: »HAUL_CYCLE_REC_IDENT«

[image: error]

The ***HAUL_CYCLE_REC_IDENT*** column in the csv file is as follows:-

[image: csv file]

What is the issue in the table's column ***HAUL_CYCLE_REC_IDENT*** datatype.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line of your CSV contains the header, so you must instruct [copy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) to ignore it.

Using the old syntax (< v9.0), you would just add `HEADER` after `CSV`, though you might want to move to the current syntax (`... WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER TRUE)`).

In your case, the `\copy` command could look like

````sh
psql -U postgres -d cycles -c "\COPY cycles_table FROM C:\Users\DEGEJOS\Downloads\TruckFleet_TruckCyclesQualityMatId.csv WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER)" ```
````

Comment: I ignored the headers of the CSV file. But there were correction in the command mentioned. There were a syntax error in that. The following command is the correct one.

`psql -U postgres -d cycles -c "\COPY cycles_table FROM C:\Users\DEGEJOS\Downloads\TruckFleet_TruckCyclesQualityMatId.csv WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER)"`